# How to make a css triangle responsive

Tags: css, css-shapes

I need to make the following triangle in css, be responsive. 
All I have currently is

```
.tri-top-right:before {
content:'';
display: block;    
border-top: 500px solid black;
border-left: 500px solid transparent;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

I have seen it done with pure css before, and not using JS (which is how the 'duplicate' answer solves it) but I am not sure how.

I've tried using a bunch of different percentage values but I cannot figure out how to change it so it resizes responsively:  http://jsfiddle.net/au7ggmg8/

I probably just need a hand in general figuring out how to make any shape responsive :)

Comment: doubt it all u like: http://jsfiddle.net/josedvq/3HG6d/